# <div title="Can I somehow put PHP code in this attribute?"></div> or is there another route I can take?

Tags: php, javascript, attributes

I want to:

1. Read in text line from "textfile.txt".
2. 'echo' that line to the page in a `<div>` element.
3. Read in a text line from "namefile.txt".
4. Make this line become some sort of pop-up-text for that `<div>` element.

My script:

```
<? PHP
$fhtext = fopen("textfile.txt","a+") or exit("Error 1");
$fhname = fopen("namefile.txt","a+") or exit("Error 2");

while(!feof($fhtext))
  {
  echo "<div title="HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK">".fgets($fhtext)."<div/><br />";
  }
```

Could I perhaps go:

```
echo "<div title="<? fgets($fhname) ?>".fgets($fhtext)."<div/><br />";
```

?

Comment: I think your basic problem is to read the data from the files, and it's not relate to HTML or javascript in any way, right?

Comment: Why did you wrote (wrong) html tags for the title? :/

Comment: @Damien Sorry, which part is wrong?

Comment: @user993683 not really wrong, but writing the content in the title attribute and not in the div itslef is not really useful. All of this, if ever it was necessary to use html in the first place; did you see any other title shaped like that? Look at the slug of this question and see why you shouldn't have used it

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$fhtext = fopen("textfile.txt","a+") or exit("Error 1");
$fhname = fopen("namefile.txt","a+") or exit("Error 2");

while(!feof($fhtext) && !feof($fhname))
{
    echo "<div title=\"", fgets($fhname), "\">", fgets($fhtext), "<div/><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please stop concatenate the strings before echo'ing them. You should have `echo 'foo', $bar;` instead of `echo 'foo'. $bar;`

Comment: (sorry if I'm not meant to comment) Thanks! So much altruism on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP in a long time, but this should work:

```
echo "<div title='" . fgets($fhname) ."'>" .fgets($fhtext). "<div/><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> 1. Make this line become some sort of pop-up-text for that '' element.

If you mean 'popup' text, as in tooltips of the type you get when you hover over links/images, this is only available on some elements when their title attribute has been set, not DIVs.

As such you can either change the DIV to a A (link) element. Or use Javascript to detect a hover over the DIV and display a popup.

Comment: Thanks Ergo. Is it possible to make tooltip-like text in js?

Comment: Yes, there are a large number of implementations available, e.g. http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure both files have the same number of lines you could use the „file“-function of PHP. This will read the file into an array and you can loop over it with a for-loop:

```
<?php
$file1 = file('file1');
$file2 = file('file2');
for ($i = 0, $max = count($file1); $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo $file1[$i].' '.$file2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you dump your `fgets()` data to the browser, you really ought to HTML encode it first. That will prevent accidental (or not so accidental) problems caused by HTML fragments that might be in your text files, or if the file name can be entered by the user (either as part of the URL or as part of a form).

As a rule of thumb, always HTML encode anything coming from a data source you don't control before spitting it out to the browser. That includes form fields, etc.